# RSS Feed and Google's XML Adapter example - Does it work?

Tags: android, xml, adapter

I'm trying to understand Google's example of XML Adapters as shown at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/index.html, especially as it related to RSS feeds.

I cannot get Google's sample code to compile.  The Adapters.java code seems to have several issues with undefined variables, `mContext`, `mFrom`, and `mTo` as used in the `XmlCursorAdapter` class.

I am new to Android and am trying to get this to work with a API level 4 program.

Has anyone gotten this example to work?  Can you offer any insight?

Comment: By the way, I created an app based on the sample code and it too has the same errors, even if I use SDK API level 11.  Google's sample code appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new
ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this,R.layout.style,feed1.getAllItems());
itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);

itemlist.setSelection(0);
```

just try this example

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete source code of the examples also in the android sdk-samples.
There is also an upated version of the XmlAdapters sample for SDK-version 15.

However, I can get it to compile, but it does not run afterwards, but I assume that's due to a configuration issue on my side. You should have a look into the source code which comes delivered right with the sdk. They can be installed via the Android SDK Manager.