# Xmlapter example not working .contains (contacts reader,Rss feeds,photos display)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-activity

I am developing  **RSS Feeds**  application from the basic google resource folder.
Right now I am display all three contents as suggested into example.

1.Contacts.
2.Photos.
3.RSS Feed

here is link:

[RSS FIELD -xmladapters](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/index.html)

I managed code very well as per my requirement .only change the package and Project name.
But its display Fatal Error:

**LOGCAT:**

```
 04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.satyamdswt.agreader/com.satyamdswt.agreader.ContactsListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The layout specified in contacts does not exist
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The layout specified in contacts does not exist
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.satyamdswt.agreader.Adapters$XmlCursorAdapterParser.parse(Adapters.java:219)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.satyamdswt.agreader.Adapters.createCursorAdapter(Adapters.java:168)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.satyamdswt.agreader.Adapters.createAdapterFromXml(Adapters.java:151)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.satyamdswt.agreader.Adapters.loadAdapter(Adapters.java:105)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.satyamdswt.agreader.Adapters.loadAdapter(Adapters.java:92)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.satyamdswt.agreader.ContactsListActivity.onCreate(ContactsListActivity.java:12)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    04-09 17:40:02.894: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  ... 11 more
```

In LogCat you see that:

```
com.satyamdswt.agreader/com.satyamdswt.agreader.ContactsListActivity
```

I don't know why this happened two times.

For more I display my Manifest.xml here:
**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.satyamdswt.agreader"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactsListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

         <activity android:name="PhotosListActivity"
                  android:label="@string/photos_list_activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".AGRssReaderActivity">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please guide me where is Error.

**ContactListActivity.java**

```
public class ContactsListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list);
        setListAdapter(Adapters.loadAdapter(this,R.xml.contacts ));
    }

}
```

**EDITED**
contacts.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cursor-adapter  xmlns:android="com.satyamdswt.agreader"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.satyamdswt.agreader"
    android:layout_width="@layout/contact_item"
    app:selection="has_phone_number = 1 "
    app:uri="content://com.satyamdswt.contacts/contacts" >



     <bind
        app:from="display_name"
        app:to="@id/name" 
         app:as="string"/>

    <bind
        app:as="drawable"
        app:from="starred"
        app:to="@id/star" >
        <map
            app:fromValue="0"
            app:toValue="@android:drawable/star_big_off" />
        <map
            app:fromValue="1"
            app:toValue="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />
    </bind>
    <bind
        app:as="com.satyamdswt.agreader.ContactPhotoBinder"
        app:from="_id"
        app:to="@id/name" />

</cursor-adapter>
```

Comment: Post also `res/xml/contacts.xml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recreated your error. Problem is in your `res/xml/contacts.xml` file

Change this line:

```
xmlns:app="com.satyamdswt.agreader"
```

to this line:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.satyamdswt.agreader"
```

It is right format of XML namespace of your app: `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/package_name`

**Upd:** You shouldn't change other parameters in the `<cursor-adapter>` tag. Right form:

```
<cursor-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.satyamdswt.agreader"
    app:uri="content://com.android.contacts/contacts"
    app:selection="has_phone_number=1"
    app:layout="@layout/contact_item">
```

Comment: ..I changed packate name.But it still not working.
I edited my contacts.xm.
Pls see is it correct format ?

Answer (score 0):

Put contacts_list.xml in your layouts folder
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/res/layout/contacts_list.html

Download the file from here and put in your layouts folder
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/res/layout/index.html

**EDIT**

I think the error is with this file 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/res/xml/contacts.html

Please check if you have the layout "contact_item" in your layout folder

You can find it here - http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/res/layout/contact_item.html

Comment: Have you made any changes to ContactListActivity? If so please post them here

Comment: I added the code for the ContactListActivity. if you required more please let me know.Have you already did this type of code?

Comment: @SDROIDRisk Also post contacts.xml, if its the same as in the example, make sure you have the required layouts and all the package names changed to whatever you ve renamed yours

Comment: Also see this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334952/rss-feed-and-googles-xml-adapter-example-does-it-work

Comment: From what you ve put I think the error is still with your layouts - I will try to run the code and tell you if it works and what changes you need to make later.

Comment: If you are going so and tell me where I need tochange to run mycode. I have no Hesitation to accept your answer.But make sure it will run.